# Getting an ERROR updating an entity with a many 2 many relationship (JOIN TABLE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have 2 entities bounded together with a join table. Creating the article works fine. Updating the article entity throws this exception:

***SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_ArticleGroups_Articles_ArticleID". The conflict occurred in database "myDB", table "dbo.ArticleGroups", column 'ArticleID'.
The statement has been terminated.***

Below is my classes and setup

Article.cs

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleGroup> ArticleGroups { get; set; } = new List<ArticleGroup>();
}
```

Group.cs

```
public class Group
{
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public string GroupName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ArticleGroup> ArticleGroups { get; set; } = new List<ArticleGroup>();
public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; set; } = new List<GroupUser>();
}
```

ArticleGroup.cs

```
public class ArticleGroup
{
   public int ArticleId { get; set; }
   public Article Article { get; set; }
   public int GroupId { get; set; }
   public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{ 
    .....
    modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.ArticleID, e.GroupId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Article)
            .WithMany(e => e.ArticleKbGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ArticleID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Group)
            .WithMany(e => e.ArticleGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}

public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
public DbSet<ArticleGroup> ArticleGroups { get; set; }
```

ArticleRepository.cs

```
public bool UpdateArticle(Article article)
    {
        var articleGroups = _appDbContext.ArticleGroups.Where(a => a.ArticleID == article.ArticleID);
        _appDbContext.ArticleGroups.RemoveRange(articleGroups);
        _appDbContext.Articles.Update(article);
        return (_appDbContext.SaveChanges() >= 0);
    }
```

I've seen similar problems with such complicated solutions that don't compare to something as trivial as this. Where in EF am I setting up incorrectly? I'm thinking its sql statements not executing in the right order?

I would think the game plan would be remove all from join table with the same articleID and insert the new values.

**EDIT**

Added relationships

User.cs

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupUser> GroupUsers { get; set; } = new List<GroupUser>();
```

GroupUser.cs

```
public class GroupUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

This is the other relationship in this as well. Would this cause the error?

I need the Groups to not be deleted as well as they could belong to another article.

**EDIT 2**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.GroupId }); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>()
            .HasOne(e => e.User)
            .WithMany(e => e.GroupUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GroupUser>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Group)
            .WithMany(e => e.GroupUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.ArticleId, e.GroupId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Article)
            .WithMany(e => e.ArticleGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ArticleId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleGroup>()
            .HasOne(e => e.Group)
            .WithMany(e => e.ArticleGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

Comment: With current your codes i didn't face the error , when do you get the error ? It won't face problem if you are deleting the `ArticleGroups` related records and then update the main `Articles`, do you have any other operations ?

Comment: How do you delete the article groups first....Group is tied to another join table Users. Users are joined to Groups and Groups are tied to Articles. All using JOIN Tables having a many-2-many relationship. Would that cause the error?

Comment: please show the related entities to help reproduce

Comment: @NanYu I've added more under Edit.....maybe this would cause the error? If so why?

Comment: It would be better if you could share us a demo to reproduce your issue, currently, we fail to reproduce your issue with shared code.

Comment: @TaoZhou I'll try to put together something tonight